# Swift 4 non-exhaustive switch compiles

Tags: swift, enums, compiler-errors, switch-statement, runtime-error

It is my understanding that in swift, a switch statement that is not exhaustive and has no default case should not compile. I was planning on using this to my advantage, since I have an enum with many cases, and I like having the compiler direct me to each switch statement that must be updated when I add a case.

```
enum Scalar {
    case unhandled
    case handled
    indirect case third(Vector2)
    indirect case fourth(Vector2,Vector2)
}
enum Vector2 {
    case handled(Scalar,Scalar)
    indirect case unhandled(Scalar,Vector2)
}
extension Scalar {
    func eval() -> Int {
        switch self {
        case .handled: return 1
        case .third: return 2
        }
    }
}
extension Vector2 {
    func eval() -> (Int,Int) {
        switch self {
        case .handled: return (3,6)
        }
    }
}
let g = Scalar.handled
print(g.eval())
let h = Scalar.unhandled
print(h.eval())
```

As it turns out, however, while most switch statements fail to compile when they are non-exhaustive, when switching over my enum, non-exhaustive switches will compile, without even raising a warning. At runtime, if the switch is hit with an enum that isn't handled by one of its cases, a runtime error is thrown.

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: unexpected enum case while switching on value of type 'Scalar'
```

I'm using OSX 10.14.2, Xcode 10.1, Swift 4.2

I'm confused, because I haven't been able to find any information about this kind of switch statement being allowed in swift. How can I make my compiler warn me when it encounters a non-exhaustive switch statement?

Comment: I've edited my question to include a minimal example. Weirdly enough, taking anything out of this example causes the problem to go away. Sorry for not having the example before.

Comment: I’m seeing the same behavior you describe. FWIW, the issue exists in Xcode 10.2 Beta w Swift 5, too. Seems worthy of a [bug report](https://bugreport.apple.com) to me!